# SQL Server CE joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have 2 tables, `tb1` is users and `tb2` is stats.

I have multiple stats for each user marked with a timestamp

I wanted a query where I could get the latest stat for each user I tried a lot of things but SQL Server CE seems a little bit limited...

Can someone give me a hint on how to perform it?

Comment: could you give us some fields in the tb2?

Comment: what have you tried? `sqlce` is limted, but getting latest stats seems to be easy task. Maybe your design makes it harder?

Comment: tb1.userid, tb1.username, tb2.userid, tb2.deaths, tb2.kills, tb2.headshots, tb2.totalmatches, tb2.lastsync

I want to present all data with only the latest stat per user

Comment: tried left outer join, right outer join, inner join, cross join :P

Comment: I feel like I am being doomed by this... I have posted more complicated question, yet I still didn't find an answer for such a trivial question :(

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an inline view that gives the latest timestamp for each user and use that to constrain the query.  Try something like the below:

```
    select tb1.userid, tb1.username, tb2.userid, tb2.deaths, tb2.kills, tb2.headshots,   tb2.totalmatches, tb2.lastsync 
    from tb1 
    inner join tb2 on tb1.1userid = tb2.userid 
    inner join (select tb2.userid, max(timestamp) as latest from tb2 group by tb2.userid) x
    on tb2.timestamp = x.latest
```

Answer (score 1):

;WITH CTE AS
(
select tb1.userid, tb1.username, tb2.userid, tb2.deaths, tb2.kills, tb2.headshots,    tb2.totalmatches, tb2.lastsync, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  tb2.timestamp DESC) row
from tb1 
Inner join tb2 on tb1.1userid = tb2.userid 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE row = 1